# Delete the other rows in a data frame except the values in a list in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame `Input` with many variables and also a list  `k` with many values that are name of variables of data frame. I am trying to Include the only values in list and create separate data frame.

```
k = [IN_15M, IN_9M, IN_6M]`
```

Input:

```
ID  OUT_3M  OUT_6M  OUT_9M  OUT_15M  IN_3M  IN_6M   IN_9M   IN_15M
A   2        3        4        6        2     3       4       6
B   3        3        5        7        3     3       5       7
C   2        3        6        6        2     3       6       6
D   3        3        7        7        3     3       7       7
```

Output:

```
ID  OUT_3M  OUT_6M  OUT_9M  OUT_15M  IN_3M  
A   2        3        4        6        2  
B   3        3        5        7        3  
C   2        3        6        6        2        
D   3        3        7        7        3
```

I have tried the following code and got an error. Can anyone help me in solving this

```
error
`Output= Input[K]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `isin`

```
k = ['IN_15M', 'IN_9M', 'IN_6M']
df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin(k)]
Out[122]: 
  ID  OUT_3M  OUT_6M  OUT_9M  OUT_15M  IN_3M
0  A       2       3       4        6      2
1  B       3       3       5        7      3
2  C       2       3       6        6      2
3  D       3       3       7        7      3
```